# twig wont load my HTML input while using if statement

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

I want to use the if statement to determine the use of readonly.
It wont show the input it's just an empty space

```
{% if Actie == Nieuw %}
<input class="numeriek" type="text" name="Netnummer" value=" 
{{Netnummer }}" maxlength="10">{% endif %}

{% if Actie == Openen %}
<input readonly class="numeriek" type="text" name="Netnummer" value=" 
{{Netnummer }}" maxlength="10"> {% endif %}`
```

I dont know what Im doing wrong.
Actie is in another file where twig loads the template

Comment: Hello,
Actie, Nieuw and Openen are variables ? Are they defined ?
If not, literal has to be between quotes

Comment: only Actie is a variable

Comment: What are `Nieuw` and `Openen` then?

Comment: Nieuw means when creating something new in the database and Openen is opening the data from the database

Comment: Is that strings as pointed @MatMouth ?

Comment: they are both strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then one of the solution is: (if Actie contains the string "Nieuw" or "Openen")

```
{% if Actie == "Nieuw" %}
<input class="numeriek" type="text" name="Netnummer" value=" 
{{Netnummer }}" maxlength="10">{% endif %}

{% if Actie == "Openen" %}
<input readonly class="numeriek" type="text" name="Netnummer" value=" 
{{Netnummer }}" maxlength="10"> {% endif %}
```

Comment: I cant see the cursor  but somehow I am still able to edit the text

Comment: Maybe you also have a css problem ?
You can try` input[type="text]{cursor: text;}`

Comment: that could be possible

Comment: where do I need to add cursor?

Comment: in a css file, loaded on your page. But by default, for an imput text, the cursor is present, and set as text: like:  input[type="text]{cursor: text;}

Answer (score 0):

You compare `Actie` against a string, you've forgot to add quotes around. `'Nieuw'` / `'Openen'`

Your condition is wrapped around the input, not around the readonly, providing code repetition.

```
<input class="numeriek" type="text" name="Netnummer" value="{{ Netnummer }}" maxlength="10"{{ (Actie == 'Nieuw') ? '' : ' readonly' }}>
```

I'm using a ternary expression, to write a condition in one line.

```
{{ (condition) : (somevalue) ? (someothervalue) }}
```

Is equivalent to :

```
{% if (condition) %}
    {{ somevalue }}
{% else %}
    {{ someothervalue }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I have used your method but when I use it I cant see the cursos but I can still edit

Comment: I edited my answer, since I now know that `Nieuw` and `Openen` are supposed to be strings instead of variables